# Puzzle on looping statement

Tags: c++, c, puzzle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not able to solve the puzzle regarding this code…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321976/not-able-to-solve-the-puzzle-regarding-this-code)

The following is a piece of C code, whose intention was to print a minus sign 20 times. But you can notice that, 
it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
      int i;
      int n = 20;
      for( i = 0; i < n; i-- )
          printf("-");
      return 0;
  }
```

Well fixing the above code is straight-forward. To make the problem interesting, you have to fix the above 
code, by changing exactly one character

Comment: For certain values of "fix". I hope a "correct" solution wouldn't pass code review.

Comment: No, you have to change it by two characters or you won't get an idiomatic C program, but a contrived bit of hacker trivia.

Comment: @larsmans: hence the "puzzle" tag, to be fair.

Answer (score 5):

1)

```
for( i = 0; i + n; i-- )
    printf("-");
```

2)

```
for( i = 0; i < n; n-- )
    printf("-");
```

3)

```
for( i = 0; -i < n; i-- )
    printf("-");
```

Comment: in `-i < n`, you "added" (as opposed to "changed") one character.

Comment: @Nawaz : well, you just need to remove the space after the ';'; then, technically, only a character is changed (a space become a minus sign).

Comment: @Luc: if that space is a part of the program and the logic, then yes, you can remove that. Otherwise, no matter how many spaces you remove, would not be counted.

Answer (score 4):

One:

```
  for( i = 0; i < n; n-- )
      printf("-");
```

Two:

```
  for( i = 0;-i < n; i-- )
      printf("-");
```

Three:

```
  for( i = 0; i + n; i-- )
      printf("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change it so that instead of i--, you do n--.